# Which way of storing and operating on bitfields in javascript is the fastest? (200k+ bits)

Tags: javascript, cordova, bit-manipulation, bit-fields

I am profiling my javascript code intended to be used on embedded browser on Android (PhoneGap).

Basically I need a very large bitfield (200k+ bits) for my calculations.

I've tried to put them into array of unsigned integers with each item storing 32 bits - this indeed reduced memory usage but made execution time *drastically* too slow (over 30 seconds for simple iterating and reversing all bits in the bitfield on modern PC!)

Than I made good old fashion array of bools. This increased memory usage (but still it was less than 15 mega on Android for entire PhoneGap framework around my code). Profiling showed me that initial step in my algorithm - setting all elements of the bitfield to 1 (simple for- loop) - takes half of the execution time (~1.5 seconds on PC, more than few minutes on Android). I can rewrite my code so default value would be 0 not 1 (reverse all conditions), but I still don't know how to set such large array to 0'es fast.

*Edit* adding my code, as requested:

```
var count = 200000;
var myArr = [];

myArr.length = count;
for(var i = 0; i < count ; i++)
    myArr[i] = true;
```

Could someone point me how can I clear very large array, or is there any faster way to store and operate on large bitfields in javascript?

Comment: Bitfields ... Javascript ... Fast ... Q: Am I the only one that sees multiple contradictions here ;)?

Comment: would you mind posting the code?

Comment: Why don't you show some basic examples of what you tried to do.

Comment: PiotrK, try Typed Arrays: http://www.khronos.org/registry/typedarray/specs/latest/ - it was a choice for Bellard's JS x86 emulator: http://bellard.org/jslinux/tech.html; supported from 4.0 http://caniuse.com/typedarrays

Comment: @MarkHubbart It's simple two-lines long for loop, but I'll add it to description right away :)

Comment: @paulsm4 I only see one contradiction, three-sided and unobvious. Bitfields in javascript are possible. Fast bitfields are possible. Fast javascript is possible. The only thing not obvious here is how to make fast bitfields in Javascript.

Comment: try posting down at [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). you may get better results.

Comment: Is it not possible to treat an `undefined` value as `true` in all your calculations? This way you skip the initialisation phase altogether.

Comment: @Asad that's pretty nice idea - do I have guarantee that array will be initialized by undefined values?

Comment: @Asad and is there any quick method to check for undefined values? I've tried if(myVar === undefined), but this is *much* slower than if(myVar)

Comment: @PiotrK That shouldn't really be the case. Could you add the code where you are doing this comparison?

Comment: There are ways to do it with join/split, but the problem with this method is it makes strings and not booleans/ints. http://jsperf.com/test-join-with-split-match The reg exp one is slow, just there for an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this is a faster way to create the array:

```
var myArray = [true];
var desiredLength = 200000;
while (myArray.length < desiredLength) {
    myArray = myArray.concat(myArray);
}
if (myArray.length > desiredLength) {
    myArray.splice(desiredLength);
}
```

[I've added a few more test cases to the `jsperf` page that Asad linked in his comment](http://jsperf.com/array-initialisation-comparison/2).  By far the fastest in my browser (Chrome 23.0.1271.101 on Mac OS X 10.8.2) is this one:

```
var count = 200000;
var myArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  myArr.push(true);
}
```

Comment: Whoa, really nice idea - unfortunately it doesn't work well, it's about 10 times slower on my PC than simple iterator over array (I've run both methods 50 times)

Comment: @Asad That depends on your JavaScript implementation.  In my browser (Chrome 23.0.1271.101 on Mac OS X 10.8.2), the `concat` version performs about twice as many operations per second as the “normal” version.  What really matters is how fast each version is in phonegap on Android.  I don't have any Android devices to test with.  I have added [a few more test cases](http://jsperf.com/array-initialisation-comparison/2) to yours.

Comment: Tested on my system, it's 3x faster in Chrome, 8x slower in FF & 3x slower in IE (than op's method).

Comment: @robmayoff I tested the `push` approach, but it was twice as slow in FF, so I gave it up. It is extremely odd that results from different JS implementations vary so much, especially since I expect the underlying algorithm to be the same.

Comment: Added Chrome 18 on Android 4.0

Answer (score 2):

Why pre-fill the array in the first place! Use `undefined` to your advantage. Remember that undefined acts as a *falsey* value. So it will act exactly like 0/false when you do a boolean check.

```
var myArray = new Array(200000);

if (myArray[1]) {   
  //I am a truthy value
} else {
  //I am a falsey value
}
```

So when you initialize the array this way, there is no reason to prefill! That means no extra processing and take advantage of the sparse Array!